# Java Convert CSV to XLSX

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that would convert .csv file to .xlsx file using Apache POI. Everything works fine except that the .xlsx file generated does not display german letters with **umlaut** (ü,ä,ö) properly. It simply prints a question mark. Would anyone be so kind as to help me with this?
Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code that I have written. I am not an expert in Java so I apologize in advance if my code seems pretty basic.

```
private static void csvtoxlsx() {
    try{
        String csvfile = "test.csv";
        String xlsxfile = "test-changed.xlsx";
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
        XSSFFont xssfFont = workbook.createFont();
        xssfFont.setCharSet(XSSFFont.ANSI_CHARSET);
        XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cellStyle.setFont(xssfFont);
        String currentLine;
        int RowNum = 0;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
        while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            String[] str = currentLine.split(";");
            RowNum++;
            XSSFRow currentRow = sheet.createRow(RowNum);
            for(int i=0; i< str.length; i++){
                str[i] = str[i].replaceAll("\"","");
                str[i] = str[i].replaceAll("=","");
                XSSFCell cell = currentRow.createCell(i);
                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                cell.setCellValue(str[i].trim());
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(xlsxfile);
        workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();

        System.out.println("success");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably reading the CV file incorrectly. Try to pass an encoding to the `FileReader`

Comment: Witch Apache POI and Java version do you use?

Comment: @SHoko I am using apache poi-ooxml 3.17 (maven dependency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass encoder like below in the BufferedReader and that would be able to read the characters properly as you expect.

```
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.csv"), "windows-1252")); // Or try "Cp1252" in place of "windows-1252"

        String lineOfText;
        while ((lineOfText = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //do something
        }
        br.close();
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: Consider the use of `Files.newBufferedReader` method (from java 8 and onwards) and close the resource properly with the `try-with-resources` statement or a `finally` block. More details here: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2095